# javascript has 3rd party object loaded

Tags: javascript, setinterval, loaded

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to check the script element load event accross browser without jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574549/how-to-check-the-script-element-load-event-accross-browser-without-jquery)

I'm writing a page to generate graphs for someone. I'm using the Google Charts API.

I want to load the API dynamically.  I'm having problems with the 'google' global object.
How can I detect whether it has been declared? If it were my own script I think I could use call back.  Currently i have :

```
var addScript = function(src){
    var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script= document.createElement('script');
    script.type= 'text/javascript';
    script.src= src;
    head.appendChild(script);
}

var init = function (){           

    addScript('https://www.google.com/jsapi');

    var waitForScript = setInterval(function(){

        if(window['google']!==undefined){
            window.clearInterval(waitForScript);
            google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
                'packages':['corechart']
            });


        }

    },50);

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use the `load` event of the dynamically created `<script>` element

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to check the script element load event accross browser without jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574549/how-to-check-the-script-element-load-event-accross-browser-without-jquery) or [dynamic script loading synchronization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774752/dynamic-script-loading-synchronization)

Answer (score 1):

The existence of a property will always autocast to true, so it will suffice to do:

```
if (window['google']) {
//do stuff
};
```

Also, in Opera you are not guaranteed to always have a `head` tag. So you do script appends like this:

```
var addScript = function(src){
    var script= document.createElement('script');
    script.type= 'text/javascript';
    script.src= src;
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: @Bergi  Thanks for the response. Will use both your solutions